# Is it possible to retrieve an integer value from a database using Oledb?

Tags: c#, oledb

My code successfully reads string values from the database, but when I want to import an integer value, it reads it as null values (even though the database has values assigned to that field)

My code:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Enemies";
da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
da.Fill(dt); // dt = DataTable
wea = new Weapon(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[randomItem][1])); // Works perfect for only string value retrieval       
// randomItem = Randomly chooses a row from the database to use for object construction
```

If I use the following code, I receive an "InvalidCastExcpetion was unhandled" exception. "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"

```
wea = new Weapon(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[randomItem][2])) // The 2 gets the damage column from the database
```

Comment: the "damage" column is really a integer value? not a numeric value?

Comment: If the column value is `NULL` what value would you want to use in it's place?

Comment: did you check whether all columns are poplated correctly?check whether u get values in damage column?

Comment: Do you have values in all rows for that column? It definitely looks like you have a null value for that specific row. Do you get the correct column? Remember that the column index is zero-based.

Comment: Yes, I have values in the column. My data type is Number, and Field Size is Integer. Should I change my Data Type?

Comment: You can check if it's DBNull (save it as object or maybe, not sure, var): `object val = dt.Rows[randomItem][1]; if (val != DBNull) wea = new Weapon((int)val);` . Not sure how to get `DBNull` thought.

Comment: Remember that columns are zero-indexed, so `dt.Rows[randomItem][1]` reads the **second** column, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for your answers, I found a solution by creating a separate variable that does the converting, then it carries the value over to the Weapon object creation. I feel like my original code was supposed to work, but it would appear it doesn't like it if you do an integer conversion after directly calling the value:

The code:

```
 int weaponDamage = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[randomItem][2]);
 wea = new Weapon(weaponDamage);
```